# SQL query to select where A='foo' and where (A='bar' and B='baz')

Tags: sql, logic

I've got the next SQL query:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE STATUS = 1 AND VARIABLE IN ( 'PR', 'AR' ) AND SPECIAL = 1;
```

SPECIAL is an additional condition which is added if I previously selected 'PR' (checkbox) in my form. The thing is, with this query, I'm no longer getting rows where VARIABLE is 'AR'.

Now, the idea is that this query should return any rows when VARIABLE is 'PR' or 'AR', but if it is 'PR', from this 'PR'-only group, it should return only the ***SPECIAL*** ones. I mean, it should still display rows with VARIABLE = 'AR', but if SPECIAL = 1, then the ones that are 'PR', should be only those where SPECIAL = 1.

Comment: `if SPECIAL = 1, then ... only those where SPECIAL = 1.` I think I know what you mean but the way you've written it is confusing.

Comment: I know, sorry. My native tongue is not english, plus I was totally freaked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is an assignment I think it is better to explain how to do it than to just to give you the code to copy and paste.

You want to select a row where STATUS = 1 **and** one of:

- VARIABLE is 'AR'

**or**:

- VARIABLE is 'PR' **and** SPECIAL = 1.

Use a combination of `AND` and `OR`. Remember that `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. It is a good idea to use parentheses to be explicit about how the expression should be calculated.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm starting to have these mind-blank shocks more frequently. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM MYTABLE WHERE 
  STATUS = 1 AND (
    VARIABLE = 'AR' OR (SPECIAL = 1 AND VARIABLE = 'PR')
  );
```

SQL has very powerful support for logical operators, you aren't limited to just AND.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding right and you want either ("AR") or ("PR" and SPECIAL = "1"), then try this:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE STATUS = 1 AND (VARIABLE = 'AR' OR (VARIABLE = 'PR' AND SPECIAL = 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need and OR statement, try this:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM MYTABLE WHERE STATUS = 1 AND ( VARIABLE = 'PR' AND SPECIAL = 1 OR VARIABLE += 'AR' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do to get this to work the way you desire is to break up the different criteria into separate logical groupings surrounded by parenthesis. If I understand your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM MYTABLE WHERE (STATUS = 1) AND ((VARIABLE = 'PR' AND SPECIAL = 1) OR (VARIABLE ='AR')) ;
```

Comment: parens aren't required around status = 1 (but it still works) and it was included in his original SQL - what's your point?

Comment: Huh? Did you complain of your own answer?

Comment: oh, strange - someone commented on my answer and then they removed their comment, I guess.